# Steps that produce a sum of 2017

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The numbers $1,2, \ldots, n$ are written in a board, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In every move, we can choose two numbers of the board, find their $\rm lcm$, and replace the two numbers with it. After $k$ moves, we find the sum of the numbers in the board, and we name it $S$. Find the minimum and the maximum value of $n$, such that there is $k$ such that $S=2017$.

This is an exercise I show at a Mathematical Forum, posted on 2017, and I have been trying this for a long time actually, and the things I have proven aren't something important, so I would prefer full answers.

As far as I now, it isn't from an exam or a Math Olympiad.

Comment: Dear Arthur, I have being trying this problem for a lot of hours, I have reached to some claims, but nothing more. if you have a solution in mind, right it down. Note: I am not English or American, so forgive possible mistakes in my expression.

Comment: General point:  people here are often reluctant to respond to "current year" questions as these are frequently used in competitions and exams.  Especially when, as here, no effort at all is shown.  (I understand it is 2018, but still).  I think you'll get a better response from the community if you edit your post to show some of the claims you have been able to prove.

Comment: I have edited. If you have a full solution, please write it. Thank you.

Comment: Any answer? How can the fact that $2016$ is a triangular number help?

Comment: How about the fact that $2017$ is a prime number?  When we replace two numbers with their $\operatorname{lcm}$, what happens to the sum?

Comment: Replace *both* the numbers with the lcm, or just one?  Find the maximum and min in terms of $k$? Or what?

Comment: @fleablood Good questions. I read it as "replace both numbers", and the min.max thing is just about "for which $n$ is this puzzle solvable?"

Comment: @Joffan Yes, I mean to find the minimum and the maximum value of $n$, such that this puzzle is solvable. (to find a $k$ for which $S=2017$).

Comment: Also, I mean replace both numbers with their $\rm lcm$

Comment: If someone has a full solution, please POST IT!

Comment: Also, lulu noted that the fact that $2016$ is a triangular number can help. Lulu? Will you answer? (Now, I saw that this post isn't here now ...)

Comment: That helps for $n=63$, not so much in general.

Answer (score 3):

Some hints (all numbers are $\in \Bbb N$).

- for any $k$, ${\rm lcm}(k,1)=k$.
- for any $j,k,$ ${\rm lcm}(j,jk)=jk$.
- the $\rm lcm$ of a prime number $p$ and any other distinct number $k$ is never less than the prime number. If $k>1,$ ${\rm lcm}(p,k)>p$.
- if we have a set of powers of distinct prime numbers, their least common multiple $({\rm lcm})$ is the product of those numbers.
- the product of a set of prime powers is greater than their sum.

Implications for the puzzle, to achieve $S=2017$:

- the sum of the maximum powers of prime numbers less than $n$ must be less than $2017$
- numbers that have multiples in the set can be removed (or retained) (including $1$).

A couple of example solutions, just for checking:

- For $n=63, $ the initial $S_0= 2016$. We can take $2,3$ as our first $\rm lcm$ pair, which are replaced with $6$ to give $S_1=2017$
- For $n=64,$ initial $S_0 = 2080$ and for a target of $2017$ we need to lose $63$. We can feed the powers of $2$ into the $\rm lcm$ calculation to replace all of $\{1,2,4,8,16,32,64\}$ with $64,$ achieving the target sum at $k=6$. Or we could use $\rm lcm$ pairs $(32,64)$ and $(31,62)$ to achieve it at $k=2$.

---

The highest value of $n$ is likely determined by the case where none of the remaining values is a multiple of any other; that is, the last set where $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor {+}1$ to $n$ sums to less that $2017$. This happens for $\fbox{$n=72$}$, when taking $(k,2k)\to 2k$ for every $k$ up to $36$ except for $k=19$ will give the required sum.

The lowest value of $n$ is at least $9$, since below that ${\rm lcm}(1..n)$ is too far below $2017$ - in particular ${\rm lcm}(1..8) = 840$. It's relatively easy to solve this, for example, for $n=24$ by assembling ${\rm lcm}$s from the original numbers in sequential pairs $\{(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),\ldots\}$ for a total of $2444$ and then disassembling some pairs and creating others appropriately to get the target value: $\{1, (2,5),$ $(3,4), 6,$ $(7,8),$ $9, 10,$ $(11,12),$ $(13,14),$ $(15,16),$ $(17,18),$ $19, 20,$ $(21,22),$ $(23,24)\}$. There will be solutions for smaller values of $n$ which use more than two numbers in ${\rm lcm}$ calculations - my smallest is $\fbox{$n=12$}$ which is achieved with $(9,10,11,12)\to 1980,$ $(1,4,6)\to 12,$ and $\{2,3,5,7,8\}$ adding in unchanged.

Comment: Thank you, but how will you find the _minimum_ value of $n$? Above you just found that $n$ can be $63$ or $64$.

Comment: I didn't find that, except incidentally. I gave a couple of examples of how the process could be used to increase or decrease $S$.

Comment: If you have a full solution, please post it.

Comment: I don't have a full solution. As a matter of interest, what's the lowest $n$ you have achieved a solution for?

Comment: The lowest $n$ I have found is $63$, as you found. If someone has a solution, even if it is partial, please post it.

Comment: Thank you, but I told you that I would like a full solution. If I see a sol, I will understand easily, and I won't waste time.

Comment: Joffan? Where is your solution?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make $S=2017$ starting from $n=11$. Merge $4, 5, 9, 11$ in any order to make the sequence $1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 1980$ which achieves the sum $2017$.

Now what is left is to prove that it is impossible to achieve the sum of $2017$ with $n=10$. Since $\gcd(1, \cdots, 10)=2520>2017$, there should be at least $2$ numbers after the process. Let them $a, b$.

It is obvious that only one of them can be multiple of $7$. WLOG, let $7|a$. Then $a\le1260$, $b\le360$. Since their sum is too small ($1260+360+360<2017$), there need to be at least $4$ numbers to make sum $2017$. Let them $a, b, c, d$.

At most $2$ of $a, b, c, d$ is multiple of $5$ and only one of them is multiple of $7$. WLOG, $a$ is multiple of $7$. If $a$ is not multiple of $5$, WLOG $b, c$ is multiple of $5$. So $a\le504$, $b\le360$, $c\le360$ and $a+b+c\le1224$. If $a$ is multiple of $5$ either, then WLOG $a, b$ is multiple of $5$ thus $a\le1260$, $b\le360$, $c\le72$ and $a+b+c\le1692$. Note that in any cases, $a+b+c\le1692$.

In all cases $d$ is not multiple of $5$ nor $7$, which means $d\le72$. Since $1692+72\times4<2017$, at least $7$ numbers at the end of process is required to make $S=2017$.

Since $k$, the number of replacements, is at most $3$ now, there are only $2$ possible cases for replacement.

- Four numbers were merged, remaining six are not touched: In this case, replaced numbers' lcm is either $2520$ or at most $1260$ and remaining numbers are too small to sum from $1260$ to $2017$.
- Three numbers merged into one, other two numbers merged, and remaining five not touched: The sum is at most $10\times9\times8+10\times9+10+\cdots+1=865<2017$.

Therefore, one cannot achieve $S=2017$ from $n=10$ and $n=11$ is the smallest possible $n$.

Comment: how do you know after 11 it will always be able to make 2017? Since there are more numbers added, the sum will change.

Comment: Oh, I need to also find the largest n too...

Comment: Ping me if you improve on my number, I'd be interested.